Have we gotten out of the business of doing set identification?
Recently this set-identification question was closed as a duplicate of a generic how-to-do-this-yourself sort of question and answer.  Was there a special reason for this to be marked as a duplicate?  Is there a new policy?  If not, it doesn't feel like it fits within the spirit of the site to close questions like this as duplicates.  I, for one, have enjoyed the stream of identification challenges and I hope that we won't close these sort of questions as duplicates unless someone reposts the same pictures or something nearly that obvious.

Related: https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/405/problems-with-set-identification-questions

I've reopened that question. We can certainly have a conversation about whether these sorts of questions are on-topic for the site, but I don't think that closing one as a dupe without that conversation is a good approach.
To address your other questions:

Was there a special reason for this to be marked as a duplicate?

There was not special a reason that I can see, but I wasn't directly involved in closing this. I'm happy to hear about any special circumstances that I may have missed here.

Is there a new policy?

There haven't been any relevant policy changes that I am aware of.

It doesn't feel like it fits within the spirit of the site to close questions like this as duplicates. I, for one, have enjoyed the stream of identification challenges and I hope that we won't close these sort of questions as duplicates unless someone reposts the same pictures or something nearly that obvious

I agree with this.
